# Loop with If-statement runs slow, too slow

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, adobe-illustrator

I am new to JavaScript. I use it to write some scripts for Adobe Illustrator.
In this script I take a selection of items, and sub-select them by some user definded values (xPointMin, xPointMax, etc.). The loop below is the main part of the function.

My problem is that this loop is terribly slow. It takes several sec. to run a selection of 50 items.

I already tried the following:

1. run the loop without any if-condition inside. This is fast.
2. run the loop with only one if-condition inside. This is as fast as with all if-conditions.

Does someone know why it is so slow or can some just make it faster.

```js
// xArray... are extracted vales from the Selection (xSel)
// xPointMin, xPointmax, xLengthMin, xLengthMay, xAreaMin, and xAreaMax are user defined values

for (var i in xSel) { // xSel is a list of selected items
  var xTF = true; // xTF is temporary variable

  // points // this will check if the given value (xArrayPoint) is within the requirements
  if (xArrayPoint[i] <= xPointMin || xArrayPoint[i] >= xPointMax) {
    xTF = false; // if so it sets the temporary variable to false
  }

  //length // same as in the first check, however we are testing the length
  if (xArrayLength[i] <= xLengthMin || xArrayLength[i] >= xLengthMax) {
    xTF = false
  }
  //area // same as in the first check, however this time we are testing area
  if (xArrayArea[i] <= xAreaMin || xArrayArea[i] >= xAreaMax) {
    xTF = false
  }

  xSel[i].selected = xTF; // changes the original value
}
}
```

Comment: never did anything for illustrator, if you do `console.log` can you see the output?, if yes, maybe you want to play with `console.time("timer_name);` and then just log the time `console.timeLog("timer_name")` and end with `console.timeEnd("tiner_name")` so you see (in ms) the amount of time per each log...

Comment: I used Date.now() to track the time. That way I narrowed it down to the code shown above and to durations given ("slow" ~ 4000 msec.; "fast" ~ 50 msec.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code could save you a lot of time for you

```
array1.forEach(i => 
    xSel[i].selected = !(
        xArrayPoint[i] <= xPointMin || xArrayPoint[i] >= xPointMax || 
        xArrayLength[i] <= xLengthMin || xArrayLength[i] >= xLengthMax || 
        xArrayArea[i] <= xAreaMin || xArrayArea[i] >= xAreaMax
    )
);
```

Let's look at what we have done over here. We did two major changes

1. **Choosing forEach over traditional for**: ForEach is considered to be faster than traditional for loops as they don't require re-initialization at every iteration.
2. **Simplifying the multiple if conditions to a single assignment statement**: As all the conditions are under OR operands, tt doesn't have to go through every condition if the first condition is true**strong text**

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The 2nd change brought me down from 4000 msec. to 2000 msec. And even lower if less statements are true. Thus, you just increased my script by 100%. 
 However, I could not get the forEach-statement running. And now I know why: Adobe is stuck on ECMA-3 (year 1999) and the forEach-statement is far to new for them (2009).  I might use a progess bar to indicate that something is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If the loop is small, you won't see why it takes so long, but the conditionals won't make much sense, for example:

if (xArrayPoint [i] <= xPointMin || xArrayPoint [i]> = xPointMax)

This is clearly true, either one value is greater than another or it is less than or equal to another, there are only these 3 possibilities, its ifs are equivalent to if (true).

Something that may make a difference (but I'm not sure about that in javascript) is to create variables inside a loop, maybe that will be expensive in terms of processing in having to allocate space in memory to save this data.

Something that optimizes a lot in search of values ​​in variables for example is the [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which is something very simple.
Say for example that you want to search for a certain value within an array, the idea of ​​the binary search is based on first placing these values ​​in ascending order and comparing the value you are comparing with the intermediate value of that array, if its value is for example higher than the intermediate value (smaller is the same idea) it will compare with the average value that is between the highest value of the array and the average value of the array, that is, it will divide the array in two until it finds the value sought.